# Where Media files (images, etc) Should Be Stored For A Websites?

Tags: image, azure-storage, media

hopefull someone can shed some light on this topic and here are some of my questions:

- How do big ecommerce websites manage their images for their websites?
- Is there any Best Practices should be consider when deciding where to keep websites images?
- I have heard to keep the images in multiple folder structure on the same server where the website is hosted so websites can render them easily and fast since they are all on same server - Is this the idea solution?
- How do professionals or big ecommerce handle images storage and maintain website images reliability and stability?
- Is Azure or AWS etc best place to store images for websites rendering?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping the files in the same server comes with more risk, if your server crashes or region goes down your application stopped as well as your files not gonna render if you are using those files separately for different applications like mobile applications.

In this case, users will also face a high loading time for those media files if the users are not in the same zone as your application hosted.

The best practice to store the image/media files on some cloud storage like S3 or Azure Blob then connect it with some CDN like CloudFront or Azure CDN.

Now you can serve your media files via CDN which will act as a global caching system for your media files.